# Polymorphism vs Inheritance. Diffrence?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I dont understand the diffrence between Polymorphism and Inheritance... They Litterarly do the same thing...

Simple Example Of Polymorphism:

```
    class shape {
    public:
        void setValues(int height_, int width_) {
            height = height_, width = width_;
        }
    protected:
        int height, width;

    private:

    };

    class rectangle :public shape, public ThreeDView{
    public:
        int area() {
            return(shape::height*shape::width);
        }
        float threeDArea() {
            return(((shape::height*shape::width)/2)*(std::cos(Z_LENGTH)));
        }
    };

class ThreeDView{
public:
    void setZLength(int value) {
        Z_LENGTH = value;
    }

    int setCompact(bool ans) {
        compact = ans;
    }

    float getZLength() {
        return Z_LENGTH;
    }

    bool getCOMPACT() {
        return compact;
    }
protected:
    float Z_LENGTH;
    bool compact;

private:
    unsigned char ZCHAR = 'Z';
};


    class triangle :public shape {
    public:
        int area() {
            return((shape::height * shape::width) / 2);
        }
    };

    int main(){
    rectangle rect2;
        triangle trng2;
        shape *poly = &rect2;
        shape *poly2 = &trng2;

        poly->setValues(2,3);
        poly2->setValues(5,4);
        std::cout << "AREA : " << trng1.area() << "AREA RECT : \n" <<rect1.area() << std::endl;
    }
```

Above example translated to Inheritance:

```
class shape {
public:
    void setValues(int height_, int width_) {
        height = height_, width = width_;
    }
protected:
    int height, width;

private:

};

class rectangle :public shape, public ThreeDView{
public:
    int area() {
        return(shape::height*shape::width);
    }
    float threeDArea() {
        return(((shape::height*shape::width)/2)*(std::cos(Z_LENGTH)));
    }
};

class triangle :public shape {
public:
    int area() {
        return((shape::height * shape::width) / 2);
    }
};

int main(){
rectangle rect2;
 triangle trng2;

    rect2.setValues(2,3);
    trng2.setValues(5,4);
    std::cout << "AREA : " << trng1.area() << "AREA RECT : \n" <<rect1.area() << std::endl;
}
```

Please tell me diffrence. Honestly i dont even see the use of Polymorphism! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Polymorphism and inheritance are two orthogonal concepts, there is simply no similarity between them only differences.

Comment: Also, your example are flawed. The first doesn't use polymorphism at all.

Comment: What is `ThreeDView`? Unless that has a virtual function you don't have any *polymorphic* types. That could be a cause of confusion.

Comment: No it doesn't. Now you've told us about `ThreeDView`, you don't have any *polymorphic types*. Do Google that term; it should help you.

Comment: Inheritance can be used as a means of achieving polymorphic behaviour. However, there are others, e.g. templates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056215/what-is-the-difference-between-polymorphism-and-inheritance

Comment: You will at some point. Thing is just: Polymorphism is an abstract programming concept that can be realized in different ways. Inheritance is one way to do that in C++. However, you can do other things with inheritance as well. The concepts are at different levels of abstraction.

Comment: Subtyping is one form of polymorphism; there are several. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version of your first example, that actually uses polymorphism:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class shape
{
public:
    void setValues(int height_, int width_)
    {
        height = height_;
        width = width_;
    }

    virtual int area() = 0;  // This is needed for polymorphism to work

    virtual std::string name() = 0;

protected:
    int height;
    int width;
};

class rectangle : public shape
{
public:
    int area()
    {
        return height * width;
    }

    std::string name()
    {
        return "Rectangle";
    }
};

class triangle :public shape
{
public:
    int area()
    {
        return height * width / 2;
    }

    std::string name()
    {
        return "Triangle";
    }
};

void print_area(shape& poly)
{
    std::cout << poly.name() << ' ' << poly.area() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    rectangle rect;
    triangle trng;

    rect.setValues(2, 3);
    trng.setValues(5, 4);

    print_area(rect);
    print_area(trng);
}
```

The first big change is that I declare the `virtual` function `area` in the `shape` class. For polymorphism to work, the functions must be declared in the base class as `virtual`. The "assignment" to `0` is simply telling the compiler that it's an *abstract* function, and the child-classes *must* override that function.

The second big change is that I use a function to print the area, one that only takes a reference to the base `shape` class. You must use references or pointers to the base class for polymrphism to work, not use the actual objects directly like in your example.

[This works as expected](http://ideone.com/d0ZJDl).